# WordPress Post Format If Statement?

Tags: excerpt, post-formats

Right now my excerpts are doubling when I use post formats.  I would like to have a default excerpt when no post format is selected.  Checkout an example: http://themeforward.com/demo2/

For my excerpts, to call post formats I am using this code:

```
<?php
if ( has_post_format( 'aside' )) {
    ?>
    <span class="icon-aside"></span>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail( 'thmb-index' ); } ?>
    </a>
    <span class="sub-title">Posted <?php the_time("F j, Y"); ?> by <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> in <?php the_category(', ') ?></span>
    <span class="index_title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></span>
    <?php the_excerpt();
}
if ( has_post_format( 'chat' )) {
    ?>
    <span class="icon-chat"></span>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail( 'thmb-index' ); } ?>
    </a>
    <span class="sub-title"><?php the_time("F j, Y"); ?> &nbsp;/&nbsp; <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> &nbsp;/&nbsp; <?php the_category(', ') ?></span>
    <span class="index_title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></span>
    <?php the_excerpt();
}
if ( has_post_format( 'gallery' )) {
    ?>
    <span class="icon-gallery"></span>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail( 'thmb-index' ); } ?>
    </a>
    <span class="sub-title">
    <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> &nbsp;/&nbsp; <?php the_category(', ') ?> &nbsp;/&nbsp; <?php the_time("F j, Y"); ?>
    </span>
    <span class="index_title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></span>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php comments_number( 'no responses', 'one response', '% responses' );
}
if ( has_post_format( 'image' )) {
    ?>
    <span class="icon-image"></span>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail( 'thmb-index' ); } ?>
    </a>
    <span class="sub-title"><?php the_time("F j, Y"); ?> &nbsp;/&nbsp; <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> &nbsp;/&nbsp; <?php the_category(', ') ?></span>
    <span class="index_title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></span>
    <?php the_excerpt();
}
if ( has_post_format( 'link' )) {
    ?>
    <span class="icon-link"></span>
    <h1><a href="<?php  echo $first_link = catch_that_link(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail( 'thmb-index' ); } ?>
    </a>
    <span class="sub-title"><?php the_time("F j, Y"); ?> &nbsp;/&nbsp; <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> &nbsp;/&nbsp; <?php the_category(', ') ?></span>
    <?php comments_number( 'no responses', 'one response', '% responses' );
}
if ( has_post_format( 'quote' )) {
    ?>
    <span class="icon-quote"></span>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail( 'thmb-index' ); } ?>
    </a>
    <span class="sub-title"><?php the_time("F j, Y"); ?> &nbsp;/&nbsp; <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> &nbsp;/&nbsp; <?php the_category(', ') ?></span>
    <span class="index_title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></span>
    <?php the_content();
}
if ( has_post_format( 'status' )) {
    ?>
    <span class="icon-status"></span>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail( 'thmb-index' ); } ?>
    </a>
    <span class="sub-title"><?php the_time("F j, Y"); ?> &nbsp;/&nbsp; <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> &nbsp;/&nbsp; <?php the_category(', ') ?></span>
    <span class="index_title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></span>
    <?php the_excerpt();
}
if ( has_post_format( 'video' )) {
    ?>
    <span class="icon-video"></span>
    <span class="sub-title"><?php the_time("F j, Y"); ?> &nbsp;/&nbsp; <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> &nbsp;/&nbsp; <?php the_category(', ') ?></span>
    <span class="index_title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></span>
    <?php the_content();
}
if ( has_post_format( 'audio' )) {
    ?>
    <span class="icon-audio"></span>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail( 'thmb-index' ); } ?>
    </a>
    <span class="sub-title"><?php the_time("F j, Y"); ?> &nbsp;/&nbsp; <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> &nbsp;/&nbsp; <?php the_category(', ') ?></span>
    <span class="index_title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></span>
    <?php the_content();
}
?>
```

...when a post format isn't selected I would like to grab this instead:

```
<!-- Begin excerpt wrap -->
<div class="excerpt_wrap">
<div class="excerpt_inside">

    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>   

    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thmb-index' ); ?>
    </a>

    <?php } ?>
    <div class="excerpt_content<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) echo ' with-thumbnail'; ?>">
    <span class="index_title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></span>
<span class="sub-title">By <?php the_author_posts_link( ); ?> <span class="sub-title-divider">|</span> <?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?> <span class="sub-title-divider">|</span> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>/#commentlist"><?php comments_number( 'No comments', 'One comment', '% comments' ); ?></a></span>

    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

    </div>

<!-- End excerpt wrap -->
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you just need to add some "elses" into your php, like so:

```
if ( has_post_format( 'aside' )) { 
    // do some stuff
} elseif ( has_post_format( 'chat' )) {
    // do some other stuff
} elseif ( has_post_format( 'gallery' )) {
    // do some other stuff
} else {
   // this isn't a post format, so do your final stuff
}
```

Hope that helps - g'luck!